# read in obscure timestamps

Tags: r, time, timestamp, read.table

I have time data in a column called `time` in the format H:M which looks like this:

```
1430 
1600 
1625 
1700 
1800 
2000
5
15 
200 
235 
400 
600 
800
```

However, occasions when the hour is during the morning it only is printed as one digit. When the hour is midnight, it is not printed at all. Likewise, if the hour is midnight and the minutes are <10, it only prints one number.

How can I read this in as H:M? I have tried:

```
time1 <- strptime(time,format = "%H%M")
```

But timestamps such as `5` get converted to `NA`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sprintf` function first :

```
data = data.frame(time = c(1430, 1600, 1625, 1700, 1800, 2000, 5, 15, 200, 235, 400, 600, 800))

data$time = sprintf("%04.f", as.numeric(data$time))
data$time = strptime(data$time ,format = "%H%M")

> print(data)
              time
1  2016-07-08 14:30:00
2  2016-07-08 16:00:00
3  2016-07-08 16:25:00
4  2016-07-08 17:00:00
5  2016-07-08 18:00:00
6  2016-07-08 20:00:00
7  2016-07-08 00:05:00
8  2016-07-08 00:15:00
9  2016-07-08 02:00:00
10 2016-07-08 02:35:00
11 2016-07-08 04:00:00
12 2016-07-08 06:00:00
13 2016-07-08 08:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks that was easy! I managed to get the desired result using an ifelse <1000 statement but this is simpler.